# Admob banner shows only on first launch

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

After following [the official](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/unity/start) Admob guide for Unity, I successfully got a banner to show up on my game. The problem is, it only shows up the very first time I build the game. If I quit the game and launch it again, it doesn't show. Deleting the game and building from Unity again is the only thing that shows banners.

My code is as follows:

```
void Start() {
    RequestBanner();
}

private void RequestBanner() {
    string id = "ca-app-pub-numbers...";
    view = new BannerView(id, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    view.LoadAd(request);
}
```

I have tried calling **view.Destroy()** on application quit or in a coroutine, as well as **view.Show()** and **view.Hide()** at various locations with no luck.

How can I make admob show banner consistently?